# How can I convert my GarageBand tune to an mp3 without the static noise increasing?

Tags: macos, garageband, mp3

After I export my GarageBand song and convert it to an mp3 and play it in iTunes, the background static noise is much louder than in Garageband.

OS X El Captain 10.11.2 . Garageband 10.1.0

I want it to sound the same as it does in GarageBand.

How can I convert tracks into an mp3 while reducing static noise in the file when played on iTunes?

Comment: What are the precise/exact steps you use to convert to mp3? Also, what version of OS and GarageBand are you using - there are quite a few and the ways to post-process a track vary widely across versions and platform.

Comment: I 'export song to disk' under 'share'. I select mp3, medium quality. OS X El Captain 10.11.2 . Garageband 10.1.0

Comment: I chatted with Apple and they suggested downloading Audacity and using Effects to reduce the static noise. I have done this and it is much better now. If anyone else has the same problem use the 'Notch Filter' first, then 'Noise Reduction' - Noise Reduction: 6, Sensitivity: 1, Frequency Smoothing: 0. You can try different settings but these worked for me.

Comment: Great work - I've added this detail to the post. Why not answer this in the answer section - you will help lots of people searching to know this question has an answer...

Comment: I'm dealing with the same nightmare trying to export mp3 files for audible.com . I spoke to a sound engineer at Warner Bros where my wife works. He suggested lowering the compressor threshold to -10 dbs to remove that increase in extraneous noise which I couldn't hear at all when editing in garageband. He said if that failed that it might be the encoding, and suggested trying another program to convert the files to mp3. I totally sympathise with this maddening problem. I haven't tried the fix yet, but have high hopes. Good luck!!!

Answer (score 1):

I suspect this is not a file compression issue but rather an *audio* compression issue. By default, GarageBand has "Auto Normalize" turned on (Preferences > Advanced). This reduces the volume difference between the softest and loudest sounds in the mix *on export*, so that the playback of the finished audio is louder. The problem is, when you've got quiet background noise in your source files, normalizing will make it louder. Try turning off "Auto Normalize" and exporting again. The file format shouldn't matter.

Of course, the Jedi master-level fix for this problem would be to get a better recording (or better recording equipment) and to EQ/filter out the noise while mixing!

Answer (score 0):

I chatted with Apple and they suggested downloading Audacity and using Effects to reduce the static noise. I have done this and it is much better now. If anyone else has the same problem use the 'Notch Filter' first, then 'Noise Reduction' - Noise Reduction: 6, Sensitivity: 1, Frequency Smoothing: 0. You can try different settings but these worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

In GarageBand change the master volume of the whole song not just the individual instrument volume, I have had the same problem as you before and it works.